# pandas fails to recognise coordinates as number

Tags: python, csv, pandas, coordinates

[image]

I have a coordinate data as csv file and I want to plot this using matplotlib.

The code I am trying to use is,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_filename='coordinate_car.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(data_filename, parse_dates=['lati', 'long'],     
encoding='cp1252')
data.columns

p_lng=data.long
p_lat=data.lati

def lat_lng_to_pixels(lat,lng):
    lat_rad=lat*np.pi/180.0
    lat_rad=np.log(np.tan((lat_rad+np.pi/2.0)/2.0))
    x=100*(lng+180.0)/360.0
    y=100*(lat_rad-np.pi)/(2.0*np.pi)
    return(x,y)

px, py=lat_lng_to_pixels(p_lat,p_lng)
```

and when I run this code, I get message as;

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Can someone help me or let me know how to handle this?

Thank you!

I add entire error code as pictures (two pictures)!

[image]

[image]

This is the data I want to use.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Currently we are missing information (such as `p_lng` and `p_lat`, imports...)

Comment: What equally important is to show the complete error traceback, indicating the exact line in which the error occurs.

Comment: I appreciate for letting me know! I am not sure how to post errors according to the rule so for now I add error message as pictures.

Comment: Alternatively, can you provide some part of `coordinate_car.csv`?

Comment: what `dtype` have `lat` and `lng` columns?

Comment: put int(lat) and also for long

Comment: why do you try to parse `['lati', 'long']` as dates?

Comment: I also add the picture of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your `['lati', 'long']` columns seem to have `object` dtype.

Here is a code for reproducing this:

```
In [23]: pd.Series(['11.1111','22.222']) * np.pi
...
skipped
...
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

**Workaround:**

```
In [28]: pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(['11.1111','22.222', 'a string']), errors='coerce') * np.pi
Out[28]:
0    34.906550
1    69.812472
2          NaN
dtype: float64
```